# Highcharts Scatter Plots Point Loading Sloppy

Tags: ios, swift, performance, graph, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to render charts on my iOS Application.

- We have been using various plot types such as column, line, scatter etc.
- All the other data points or ranges in most of plot types render correctly
- Issue is with scatter plot type, the rendering of points is really slow even though I have optimised as much as I could.

---

My Dataset is also not that large. Even for rendering two or three points it looks painfully slow.

Can someone suggest where I could be going wrong?

Also feel free to suggest any packages or modules. I researched and found Boost module but thats basically for a large dataset. Here, I would be concerned with 80-100 points at max.

Here is the service class I am using to render `chartOptions`

```
final class GraphService {
  
  private let chartOptions = HIOptions()
  private let title  = HITitle()
  private let chart = HIChart()
  private let xAxis = HIXAxis()
  private let yAxis = HIYAxis()
  private let plotOptions = HIPlotOptions()
  
  public func getGraphOptions() -> HIOptions {
    configureGraphProperties()
    setXPlot()
    setYPlot()
    formScatterPoints()
    return chartOptions
  }
}

// MARK: - Graph Properties

extension GraphService {
  private func configureGraphProperties() {
    setTitle()
    setChartType()
  }
  
  private func setTitle() {
    title.text = "Demo Scatter Graph"
    chartOptions.title = title
  }
  
  private func setChartType() {
    chart.type = "scatter"
    chartOptions.chart = chart
  }
}

// MARK: - Set X Plot

extension GraphService {
  private func setXPlot() {
    xAxis.tickWidth = 0.10
    xAxis.tickLength = 5
    xAxis.tickInterval = 1
    
    xAxis.labels = HILabels()
    xAxis.labels.allowOverlap = false
    
    xAxis.categories = ["2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022", "2023"]
    chartOptions.xAxis = [xAxis]
  }
}

// MARK: - Set Y Plot

extension GraphService {
  private func setYPlot() {
    let yTitle = HITitle()
    yAxis.title = yTitle
    yAxis.title.text = "mg/dl"
    
    yAxis.startOnTick = false
    yAxis.endOnTick = false
    yAxis.max = 193.2
    yAxis.min = 0
    yAxis.tickAmount = 4
    
    chartOptions.yAxis = [yAxis]
  }
}

// MARK: - Form Scatter Points

extension GraphService {
  private func formScatterPoints() {
    let scatter = HIScatter()
    scatter.color = HIColor(name: "rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)")
    scatter.data = [[7, 143.8]]
    chartOptions.series = [scatter]
    plotOptions.scatter = scatter
    chartOptions.plotOptions = plotOptions
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I forwarded your question to the Highcharts iOS expert, and I'll back with the answer as soon as possible. Regards!

Comment: The data array should be in the following format: scatter.data = [7, 143.8]. However, it would be helpful if you could provide a full example so that we can investigate further.

Comment: This should not make a difference. Since there's only a single element in array. Even a single point is taking a lot of time to render. Can iOS experts look into this. Just try and render a single scatter point on a demo app, will take ages compared to other plot types. What else apart from the code snippet do you want. Let me know

Comment: Apologize for the late response. The code snippet that you sent should work correctly so it would be necessary to provide the full configuration code. In case you think it seems to be a bug, you can contact the IOS developer directly on GitHub https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios/issues